# How to calculate uncertainty for a simple pendulum formula?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, error-analysis

$$ T =  2\pi \sqrt{\frac{l}{g}}$$

$$U_{c}(T) =?$$

That's the only thing my teacher left me with. I don't understand how am I supposed to solve this without any measurements.

Comment: Could you give more background? E.g., *uncertainty* may mean different things, if this is a quantum mechanics course, a course on the theory of random processes or simply mechanics course.

Comment: This is a college level physics lab. Uncertainty is a measurement uncertainty (type A, type B).

Comment: Do you measure time or the length of the pendulum?

Comment: I guess professor meant time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It you measure the period directly, then you do not need formula - the error is determined by your measurement device + the reaction time, if you need to switch it on/off (like a chronometer).

On the other hand, if you measure the length of the pendulum, then it is necessary to *propagate the error* using the equation:
$$\Delta T = \left|\frac{\partial T(l,g)}{\partial l}\right|\Delta l + \left|\frac{\partial T(l,g)}{\partial g}\right|\Delta g,$$
where $\Delta T, \delta l, \Delta g$ are the errors in period, pendulum length and the free fall acceleration. Assuming that $g$ is known (you probably do not measure it), the equation reduces to
$$\Delta T = \left|\frac{d T(l)}{d l}\right|\Delta l = \pi\frac{\Delta l}{\sqrt{gl}}.$$
You can take as $\Delta l$ the smallest possible measurement on the ruler or whatever you use to measure the length.

Comment: Спасибо Вадим, все понятно теперь. Thank you.

Comment: Your formula is the worst case scenario, which is usually used if the predictor variables are dependent. Why are the two predictors not independent of each another?